Publishing Flutter plugin privately
I am trying to privately publish my Flutter plugin, so that I can give access to it only to my company clients.
I read here that I can host my plugin in Gitlab, which I did, and now I am stuck on how do I share it with my company clients. Is it even possible to do so? If not, what could be my alternatives? I read about OnePub, but ideally, I would like to have full control over who is accessing my plugin.

you can add it to github as a private repo and add the url of that in pubspec.yaml add your company clients as a collaboratos in that repository.

Thank you! Maybe you know if the same can be done with Gitlab?

maybe that can also be done but I have'nt used Gitlab. so I don't know what will be the process.

Option 1:

Create a GitLab Account: Set up a GitLab account, for example, "my_repo_customer". This account will have access to a private repository.

Generate and Connect SSH Key: Generate an SSH key and link it to this GitLab account.

User Access: Any user using this SSH key will be identified as "my_repo_customer" and will have access to the private repository.


Note: This method can be a bit complex to set up.
Option 2:

Remote Storage: Store your package in a remote storage location that is accessible via an access token.

Download Script: Create a script that downloads the package using the access token and saves it locally.

Client Code: In your client's pubspec.yaml, use the path attribute to reference the locally saved package.


This approach simplifies package distribution by utilizing a remote storage solution.
